# Address input as text area

Tags: database, input, interface

I can't find a way how to input addresses for international users. I came to a conclusion that text area and entering address as they would on letters would be the best. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not a good idea to mix up data and representation in a database. First, you can't change the representation without great effort. Second, you can't use the data other than the one intended purpose, e.g. to do statistics (at least not without substancial effort).

For a address, you can cover most addresses with these fields:

- Title *(like Dr.)*
- Firstname
- Name
- Grade *(like MSc, PhD)*
- Company
- Street *(including house number)*
- Postal Code
- City
- State
- Country

Maybe you might want a field "addtion to address" for something like "c/o Max Meier", depending on your use case. If any of the fields above is empty (like Grade or Company), you can leave them out when generating address part of your letters.

The field street should store the name of the street stores the street name as well as the house number, as this can strongly differ between countries: In Germany, it would be "Hauptstraße 11", in Vietnam "53 Quang Trung".